# DbContext error in installer project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, installation, dbcontext

I use [installer project](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d&bvm=bv.114195076,d.bGQ) in Visual Studio 2013. There is Installer class in my assembly with this code

```
protected override void OnAfterInstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
        base.OnAfterInstall(savedState);
        try
        {
            ClientDbContext db = new ClientDbContext();
            MessageBox.Show(db.Settings.Any().ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToDetails(), "Client OnAfterInstall");
        }
}
```

I have connection string in app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ClientDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Db;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Db.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

On AfterInstall event i always catch exception

> No connection string named 'ClientDbContext' could be found in the
>   application config file

If I pass connection string to `ClientDbContext` constructor I'll catch exception

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections

How to fix this problem?

Comment: What is the purpose of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to open dbcontext and save some data which was entered on installer dialogs to "Setting" table.